# Parsing JSON with no title with volley tutorial slidenerd

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I watched slidenerd tutorial on youtube. I wnat to get json. I can not get my json. I think the problem is when I'm parsing json but I can not see it. This is my request method

```
    public static JSONObject requestMoviesJSON(RequestQueue requestQueue, String url) {
    JSONObject response = null;
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> requestFuture = RequestFuture.newFuture();

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url,
            (String)null, requestFuture, requestFuture);

    requestQueue.add(request);
    try {
        response = requestFuture.get(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        L.m(e + "");
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        L.m(e + "");
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        L.m(e + "");
    }
    return response;
}
```

This is how I get response

```
    JSONObject response = Requestor.requestMoviesJSON(requestQueue, "http://my_url");
    ArrayList<Milkbox> listMilkboxes = Parser.parseMilkboxesJSON(response);
```

This is my parse function

```
parseMilkboxesJSON(JSONObject response) {
    ArrayList<Milkbox> listMilkbox = new ArrayList<>();

    if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
        try {
            JSONArray arrayMilkboxes = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayMilkboxes.length(); i++) {
                int id = -1;
                long phone = -1L;
                long imei = -1L;
                String city = Constants.NA;
                String address = Constants.NA;

                JSONObject currentMilkbox = arrayMilkboxes.getJSONObject(i);

                id = currentMilkbox.getInt(KEY_ID);
                phone = currentMilkbox.getLong(KEY_PHONE);
                imei = currentMilkbox.getLong(KEY_IMEI);
                city = currentMilkbox.getString(KEY_CITY);
                address = currentMilkbox.getString(KEY_ADDRESS);


                Milkbox milkbox = new Milkbox();
                milkbox.set_id(id);
                milkbox.set_phone(phone);
                milkbox.set_imei(imei);
                milkbox.set_city(city);
                milkbox.set_address(address);

                listMilkbox.add(milkbox);
                text = id + " " + phone + " " + imei + " " + city + " " + address;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
        //      L.t(getActivity(), listMovies.size() + " rows fetched");
    }

    return listMilkbox;
}
```

I don't know is it correct to do so `JSONArray arrayMilkboxes = new JSONArray(response);`. Guys, is it correct the way I'm parsing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you declaring KEY_ID as a constant string, so I'll assume that you want to use KEY_ID as your token to get your integer value. Therefore all you need to do is add " " around your tokens. The methods of a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) need string as arguments to fetch tokens.

```
Milkbox milkbox = new Milkbox();
milkbox.set_id( currentMilkbox.getInt("KEY_ID") );
milkbox.set_phone( currentMilkbox.getLong("KEY_PHONE") );
milkbox.set_imei( currentMilkbox.getLong("KEY_IMEI") );
milkbox.set_city( currentMilkbox.getString("KEY_CITY") );
milkbox.set_address( currentMilkbox.getString("KEY_ADDRESS") );
```

Answer (score 4):

No its not your parsing `JSONObject` to `JSONArray`, get your response in `String` then parse it `JSONArray`

public void requestMoviesJSON(RequestQueue requestQueue, String url) {

```
    public void requestMoviesJSON(RequestQueue requestQueue, String url) {
    StringRequest jobj = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            ArrayList<Milkbox> listMilkbox = new ArrayList<>();

            if (response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                try {

                    JSONArray arrayMilkboxes = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayMilkboxes.length(); i++) {
                        int id = -1;
                        long phone = -1L;
                        long imei = -1L;
                        String city = Constants.NA;
                        String address = Constants.NA;

                        JSONObject currentMilkbox = arrayMilkboxes.getJSONObject(i);

                        id = currentMilkbox.getInt(KEY_ID);
                        phone = currentMilkbox.getLong(KEY_PHONE);
                        imei = currentMilkbox.getLong(KEY_IMEI);
                        city = currentMilkbox.getString(KEY_CITY);
                        address = currentMilkbox.getString(KEY_ADDRESS);


                        Milkbox milkbox = new Milkbox();
                        milkbox.set_id(id);
                        milkbox.set_phone(phone);
                        milkbox.set_imei(imei);
                        milkbox.set_city(city);
                        milkbox.set_address(address);

                        listMilkbox.add(milkbox);
                        text = id + " " + phone + " " + imei + " " + city + " " + address;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
                //      L.t(getActivity(), listMovies.size() + " rows fetched");
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            volleyError.printStackTrace();

        }
    });
    jobj.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 3,
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue.add(jobj);
}
```

and now call requestMoviesJSON(requestQueue,url) methed where you want do to network call.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but I don't know how to convert JSONObject to string